# How to change UIAlertAction font?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

is there a way to change UIAlertAction font, since I only found how to change font only in title and message of the UIAlertController. I also found how to change the colour, but I just can't found a way how to change the font.

Answer (score -1):

```
let titleAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: Constant.Strings.cancelAbsence, 
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name:"FONT_NAME",size: FONT_SIZE)]
)

let messageAttributed = NSMutableAttributedString(
        string: Constant.Strings.cancelAbsence, 
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name:"FONT_NAME",size: FONT_SIZE)]
)

let alertController = UIAlertController(
    title: "",
    message: "",
    preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.YOUR_STYLE
)

alertController.setValue(titleAttributed, forKey : "attributedTitle")
alertController.setValue(messageAttributed, forKey : "attributedMessage")
present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this only changes the font of the UIAlertController title font.

Comment: That is still only for a message, not for the actions (buttons)

Comment: The iOS system doesn't provide the API for us to do it.So we'd better use third party libraries.

Comment: It's hard to change it because the iOS system doesn't provide the API for us to do it. So we'd better use third party libraries